# How to pass arraylist of class from one activity to another activity onclick of adapter Textview

Tags: android

This my class which implements Serializable and onclick of one textview I am passing arraylist from one activity to other activity, but while retrieving there some problem please help out if someone aware of this type of issue.

```
public class RoomCategoryList implements Serializable {
        @SerializedName("roomCode")
        @Expose
        private String roomCode;
        @SerializedName("roomCategoryCode")
        @Expose
        private String roomCategoryCode;
        @SerializedName("roomCategoryName")
        @Expose
        private String roomCategoryName;
        @SerializedName("roomType")
        @Expose
        private String roomType;
        @SerializedName("boardData")
        @Expose
        private BoardData boardData;
        @SerializedName("roomImages")
        @Expose
        private List<String> roomImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        @SerializedName("roomAllotment")
        @Expose
        private int roomAllotment;
        @SerializedName("listPrice")
        @Expose
        private double listPrice;
        @SerializedName("offerPrice")
        @Expose
        private double offerPrice;
        @SerializedName("refundable")
        @Expose
        private boolean refundable;
        @SerializedName("roomCategoryAdjustment")
        @Expose
        private int roomCategoryAdjustment;
        @SerializedName("cancelPolicy")
        @Expose
        private List<CancelPolicy> cancelPolicy = new ArrayList<CancelPolicy>();
        @SerializedName("bedBankAdditionalData")
        @Expose
        private String bedBankAdditionalData;
        @SerializedName("hotelInformations")
        @Expose
        private List<HotelInformation> hotelInformations = new ArrayList<HotelInformation>();
        @SerializedName("facilities")
        @Expose
        private List<Facility> facilities = new ArrayList<Facility>();
        @SerializedName("currency")
        @Expose
        private String currency;

        public String getRoomCode() {
            return roomCode;
        }

        public void setRoomCode(String roomCode) {
            this.roomCode = roomCode;
        }

        public String getRoomCategoryCode() {
            return roomCategoryCode;
        }

        public void setRoomCategoryCode(String roomCategoryCode) {
            this.roomCategoryCode = roomCategoryCode;
        }

        public String getRoomCategoryName() {
            return roomCategoryName;
        }

        public void setRoomCategoryName(String roomCategoryName) {
            this.roomCategoryName = roomCategoryName;
        }

        public String getRoomType() {
            return roomType;
        }

        public void setRoomType(String roomType) {
            this.roomType = roomType;
        }

        public BoardData getBoardData() {
            return boardData;
        }

        public void setBoardData(BoardData boardData) {
            this.boardData = boardData;
        }

        public List<String> getRoomImages() {
            return roomImages;
        }

        public void setRoomImages(List<String> roomImages) {
            this.roomImages = roomImages;
        }

        public int getRoomAllotment() {
            return roomAllotment;
        }

        public void setRoomAllotment(int roomAllotment) {
            this.roomAllotment = roomAllotment;
        }

        public double getOfferPrice() {
            return offerPrice;
        }

        public void setOfferPrice(double offerPrice) {
            this.offerPrice = offerPrice;
        }

        public double getListPrice() {
            return listPrice;
        }

        public void setListPrice(double listPrice) {
            this.listPrice = listPrice;
        }

        public boolean isRefundable() {
            return refundable;
        }

        public void setRefundable(boolean refundable) {
            this.refundable = refundable;
        }

        public int getRoomCategoryAdjustment() {
            return roomCategoryAdjustment;
        }

        public void setRoomCategoryAdjustment(int roomCategoryAdjustment) {
            this.roomCategoryAdjustment = roomCategoryAdjustment;
        }

        public List<CancelPolicy> getCancelPolicy() {
            return cancelPolicy;
        }

        public void setCancelPolicy(List<CancelPolicy> cancelPolicy) {
            this.cancelPolicy = cancelPolicy;
        }

        public String getBedBankAdditionalData() {
            return bedBankAdditionalData;
        }

        public void setBedBankAdditionalData(String bedBankAdditionalData) {
            this.bedBankAdditionalData = bedBankAdditionalData;
        }

        public List<HotelInformation> getHotelInformations() {
            return hotelInformations;
        }

        public void setHotelInformations(List<HotelInformation> hotelInformations) {
            this.hotelInformations = hotelInformations;
        }

        public List<Facility> getFacilities() {
            return facilities;
        }

        public void setFacilities(List<Facility> facilities) {
            this.facilities = facilities;
        }

        public String getCurrency() {
            return currency;
        }

        public void setCurrency(String currency) {
            this.currency = currency;
        }
    }
```

I want to send this arraylist to another activity, any help

Answer (score 1):

```
For passing Arraylist from one activity A to another activity B, you can refer following code.

In Activity A: 
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
Bundle bundleList = new Bundle();
        bundleList.putSerializable("your string", (Serializable) mArrayList);
intent.putExtras(bundleList);

In Activity B:
Intent intent = getIntent();`enter code here`
ArrayList<String> list =  (ArrayList<String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("your string");
```

For better performance, you should use Parceleable instead of Serializable

Comment: No it's not working for me I used same code what u gave above but still it's not working

Comment: Are you extracting the list in a fragment or in an activity class.Also can you put your code for retrieving this list.

Comment: This is how I am retrieving   roomCategoryLists = (ArrayList<RoomCategoryList>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("rooms");

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an ArrayList the same way, if the E type is Serializable.

Example:

putExtra first Activity

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList)
```

getIntent in second Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, LihatDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ROOMS", roomCategoryList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Second Activity
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mylist");
please debug and check.